# how do I collapse grouping and keep group totals visible

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

how can i collapse grouping BUT keep column group totals visible?

i am using the lastest version from git and testing on the grouping example.

cheers,
trav.

Comment: Perhaps accept some answers on your other questions, the folks here will be a lot more helpful.

Comment: found answer:  dataView.setAggregators(column, true); // set to true to collapse but keep totals